# Python Pandas fill missing zipcode with values from another datafrane based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset in which I add coordinates to cities based on zip-codes but several of these zip-codes are missing. Also, in some cases cities are missing, states are missing, or both are missing. For example:

```
     ca_df[['OWNER_CITY', 'OWNER_STATE', 'OWNER_ZIP']] 

     OWNER_CITY OWNER_STATE OWNER_ZIP
   495  MIAMI SHORE PA
   496      SEATTLE
```

However, a second dataset has city, state & the matching zip-codes. This one is complete without any missing values.

```
df_coord.head() 

    OWNER_ZIP   CITY    STATE    
 0  71937   Cove        AR   
 1  72044   Edgemont    AR   
 2  56171   Sherburn    MN
```

I want to fill in the missing zip-codes in the first dataframe if:

1. Zip-code is empty
2. City is present
3. State is present

This is an all-or-nothing operations means, either all three criteria are met and the zip-code gets filled or nothing changes.

However, this is a fairly large dataset with > 50 million records so ideally I want to vectorize the operation by working column-wise.

Technically, that would fit np.where *but* as far as I know, np.where only takes of condition in the following format:

```
df1['OWNER_ZIP'] = np.where(df["cond"] ==X, df_coord['OWNER_ZIP'], "")
```

How do I ensure I only fill missing zip-codes when all conditions are met?

Comment: empty values are missing values or empty strings?

Comment: Missing values.

Answer (score 2):

Given `ca_df`:

```
    OWNER_CITY OWNER_STATE OWNER_ZIP
0  Miami Shore     Florida       111
1  Los Angeles  California       NaN
2      Houston         NaN       NaN
```

and `df_coord`:

```
  OWNER_ZIP         CITY       STATE
0       111  Miami Shore     Florida
1       222  Los Angeles  California
2       333      Houston       Texas
```

You can use [pd.notna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) along with [pd.DataFrame#index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) like this:

```
inferrable_zips_df = pd.notna(ca_df["OWNER_CITY"]) & pd.notna(ca_df["OWNER_STATE"])
is_inferrable_zip = ca_df.index.isin(df_coord[inferrable_zips_df].index)

ca_df.loc[is_inferrable_zip, "OWNER_ZIP"] = df_coord["OWNER_ZIP"]
```

with `ca_df` resulting as:

```
    OWNER_CITY OWNER_STATE OWNER_ZIP
0  Miami Shore     Florida       111
1  Los Angeles  California       222
2      Houston         NaN       NaN
```

I've changed the `""` to `np.nan`, but if you still wish to use `""` then you just need to change `pd.notna(ca_df[...])` to `ca_df[...] == ""`.

Comment: This is pretty good, but I get the following error:

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Both frames do not share any index or ID.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine numpy.where statements to combine multiple rules. This should give you the array of row indices which abide to each of the three rules:

```
np.where(df["OWNER_ZIP"] == X) and np.where(df["CITY"] == Y) and np.where(df["STATE"] == Z)
```

Comment: I like this solution for its simplicity, but when I write:

       df_in['OWNER_ZIP'] = np.where(df["OWNER_ZIP"] == '') and np.where(df["OWNER_CITY"] == df_coord["CITY"]) and np.where(df["OWNER_STATE"] == df_coord["STATE"]), df_coord['OWNER_ZIP'], df_in['OWNER_ZIP'])

I get a syntax error

Comment: the      df["OWNER_ZIP"] == ''    Is a syntax error, as you are missing quotation marks to make it match an empty string.
The last part is also not quite clear to me what you are doing with the df_coord['OWNER_ZIP'] and df_in['OWNER_ZIP'], it looks like you are passing 3 arguments to the numpy.where function. if you can break up each part in a working numpy.where() call and then concatenate with "and", it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print (df_coord)
   OWNER_ZIP         CITY STATE
0      71937         Cove    AR
1      72044     Edgemont    AR
2      56171     Sherburn    MN
3        123  MIAMI SHORE    PA
4        789      SEATTLE    AA

print (ca_df)
  OWNER_ZIP   OWNER_CITY OWNER_STATE
0       NaN          NaN         NaN
1     72044     Edgemont          AR
2     56171          NaN          MN
3       NaN  MIAMI SHORE          PA
4       NaN      SEATTLE         NaN
```

---

First is necessary test if same dtypes in columns matching:

```
#or convert ca_df['OWNER_ZIP'] to integers
df_coord['OWNER_ZIP'] = df_coord['OWNER_ZIP'].astype(str)

print (df_coord.dtypes)
OWNER_ZIP    object
CITY         object
STATE        object
dtype: object

print (ca_df.dtypes)

OWNER_ZIP      object
OWNER_CITY     object
OWNER_STATE    object
dtype: object
```

Then filter for each combinations of columns - missing and non missing values and add new data by `merge`, then convert index to same like filtered data and assign back:

```
mask1 = ca_df['OWNER_CITY'].notna() & ca_df['OWNER_STATE'].notna()  & ca_df['OWNER_ZIP'].isna()
df1 = ca_df[mask1].drop('OWNER_ZIP', axis=1).merge(df_coord.rename(columns={'CITY':'OWNER_CITY','STATE':'OWNER_STATE'})).set_index(ca_df.index[mask1])
ca_df.loc[mask1, ['OWNER_ZIP','OWNER_CITY','OWNER_STATE']] = df1

mask2 = ca_df['OWNER_CITY'].notna() & ca_df['OWNER_STATE'].isna()  & ca_df['OWNER_ZIP'].isna()
df2 = ca_df[mask2].drop(['OWNER_ZIP','OWNER_STATE'], axis=1).merge(df_coord.rename(columns={'CITY':'OWNER_CITY','STATE':'OWNER_STATE'})).set_index(ca_df.index[mask2])
ca_df.loc[mask2, ['OWNER_ZIP','OWNER_CITY','OWNER_STATE']] = df2

mask3 = ca_df['OWNER_CITY'].isna() & ca_df['OWNER_STATE'].notna()  & ca_df['OWNER_ZIP'].notna()
df3 = ca_df[mask3].drop(['OWNER_CITY'], axis=1).merge(df_coord.rename(columns={'CITY':'OWNER_CITY','STATE':'OWNER_STATE'})).set_index(ca_df.index[mask3])
ca_df.loc[mask3, ['OWNER_ZIP','OWNER_CITY','OWNER_STATE']] = df3

print (ca_df)
  OWNER_ZIP   OWNER_CITY OWNER_STATE
0       NaN          NaN         NaN
1     72044     Edgemont          AR
2     56171     Sherburn          MN
3       123  MIAMI SHORE          PA
4       789      SEATTLE          AA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a left join on these dataframes considering join on the columns 'city' and 'state'. That would give you the zip-code corresponding to a city and state if both values are non-null in the first dataframe (`OWNER_CITY, OWNER_STATE, OWNER_ZIP`) and since it would be a left join, it would also preserve your rows which either don't have a zip-code or have null/empty city and state values.

Comment: That's actually how I join coordinates over the OWNER_ZIP column. 

Practically speaking, can I do a join over OWNER_ZIP OR (State & City) 

?